# Use CXF JAXRSServerFactoryBean to return simple text for tests of communication failures

Tags: json, testing, jax-rs, cxf

I'm working on a codebase that attempts to make a REST call to a remote service, which returns JSON.  The call works fine when it gets normal JSON back.  In some cases, like when the network blows up, it gets back HTML, which tries to report various network problems.

Our error handling code in the client needs to deal properly with this situation, which is defined as simply obtaining the HTML string and logging it.

I find it's a little hard to write an automated test for this.

In our client code, we use `ClientBuilder.newBuilder()...` , then call "`build()`", which returns the Client, and then we call "`client.target(url)`" and then move forward with getting the response.  We have an exception handler that will attempt to read the raw text.

In a test for this kind of thing, I'm used to using the CXF `JAXRSServerFactoryBean` class to run a server.  I know how to connect the client to the server, but I'm not sure what to configure in the server to allow me to return arbitrary text, instead of a "resource class".

It's also possible that using `JAXRSServerFactoryBean` is overkill for this, as it just needs to return plain text.

What are my options here?

**Update**:

I did make progress setting up a test using JAXRSServerFactoryBean, but I'm still wondering if there are other options, especially ones that mitigate the next problem that I discovered, described at [Using javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder in CXF to create Client, any route to be able to use local transport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48235893/using-javax-ws-rs-client-clientbuilder-in-cxf-to-create-client-any-route-to-be) .

**Update**:

I gave up on the JAXRSServerFactoryBean approach, as I don't need to test the network, and doing so adds additional complications.  The JAX-RS filter approach is simpler and avoids those complications.  See the above linked question for details.