# Using javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder in CXF to create Client, any route to be able to use local transport?

Tags: jax-rs, cxf

I work on a codebase that uses the standard "`javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder`" class, from the CXF distribution, to configure and create a "`javax.ws.rs.client.Client`".

This works well enough.

I'm now trying to write tests that use `JAXRSServerFactoryBean` to manage a fake server using a controller defined by an inline class.  I can set my host:port to localhost:something, both in the test and in the client configuration, and this works well enough to allow me to test our MessageBodyReaders and Http exception handling.

However, I think this won't be "scalable", as each fake server will have to run on a "dedicated" port (while running the test, at least).  I can try to use uncommon ports, and have different tests use different ports, or use random numbers, but that's all somewhat risky.  I don't really want CI builds to fail because tests running in parallel ended up using the same port.

I read about the ability in CXF (not JAX-RS) to use "local transport" (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CXF20DOC/JAXRS+Testing).  It appears that might resolve my problem.  I need to verify this, but it's possible that two tests running in parallel both using local transport will not conflict.

However, I can't even get this to work yet, because our client code is using the "standard" JAX-RS client class, not the CXF one.  They appear to be different and incompatible.

At the point where I create the client, I tried to do this (just to see if it can work):

```
WebClient.getConfig(client).getRequestContext().put(LocalConduit.DIRECT_DISPATCH, Boolean.TRUE);
```

Unfortunately, this fails with "Not a valid Client" in "`org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.getConfig(Object)`" because it needs to be an instance of "`org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.Client`", not `javax.ws.rs.client.Client`.

Is there any easy (or even possible) path forward here?

Comment: Do you need to test “the network”?  If not, you might be able to test your client using a ClientRequestFilter (part of the JAX-RS 2.0 spec).  It has an abortWith method that allows you to mock a server’s response.

Comment: Looks promising. I definitely do not want to test the network if I don't have to.

Comment: I've got this working. You can write a real answer, or I'll write one with what I ended up doing.

Comment: Thanks David - I posted an official answer - if you have additional feedback - like any hints that might help others trying to do the same thing, please comment.  Glad to you hear that you got it working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ClientRequestFilters](https://jax-rs.github.io/apidocs/2.1/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientRequestFilter.html) to unit test JAX-RS clients.  Basically register a custom ClientRequestFilter to your Client object (or ClientBuilder) that mocks your response using the `abortWith(Response)` method on the `ClientRequestContext` object that is passed in to the filter method.

Something like this should work:

```
public MyMockRequestFilter implements ClientRequestFilter {
  @Override
  public void filter(ClientRequestContext requestContext) {
    MyEntity entity = // get the entity you want to mock as returned from the server
    requestContext.abortWith(Request.ok(entity).build());
  }
}
...
ClientBuilder builder = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().register(MyMockRequestFilter .class)
```

Hope this helps,
Andy